# HTTP GET request to StackExchange API doesn't return in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stackexchange-api

I made a GET request to get a user by ID, but it doesn't seem to work (nothing happens at all). I am using my user ID so I know the user exists. I get no error message.

Here is my AngularJS code :

```
myApp.controller('mainpage', ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', 'AuthService', 'sharedPropertie', function ($scope, $http, $resource, AuthService, sharedPropertie) {

$scope.test='7194489';
$scope.user=[];

 $http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/'+$scope.test+'?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow')
  .then(function(value) {
    console.log('value in mainpage'+value);
       $scope.user.push(value);
      });
}]);
```

And my view:

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="meetupsController">
  <div ng-controller="routeController">
           <a ng-click='gotoprive()' class="btn btn-default">Prive</a>
           <a ng-click='gotopublicforum()' class="btn btn-default">Forum public</a>
           <a ng-click='logout()' class="btn btn-default">logout</a>
           <a ng-click='topublicforumgw()' class="btn btn-default">public forum</a>
           <a ng-click='toprivateforumgw()' class="btn btn-default">private forum</a>
           <a ng-click='toaccesscontrol()' class="btn btn-default">accesscontrol</a>
           <a ng-click='tomessengergw()' class="btn btn-default">messenger</a>
           <a ng-click='topopulatedforumgw()' class="btn btn-default">populated forum</a>
         </div>
    <h1>{{user[0]}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does it not log anything? If not, change it to `.then(console.log, console.log)` and see what happens.

Comment: hey 10x for your comment. It doesnt log anything. where should i pput .then(console.log, console.log)

Comment: After `$http.get`, where you currently have the `.then` - just replace that with my suggestion and see what gets logged.

Comment: nothing gets displayed @Aurora0001

Comment: That's odd. Try doing a `console.log('Hello world!')` **before** the `$http.get` - I wonder if the controller code is ever being run at all.

Comment: Did you mean for `<div ng-controller="meetupsController">` to be `<div ng-controller="mainpage">`, or do you have code for that controller too?

Comment: You were right i didnt use the right ctrler in my view post you answer so i can accep it @Aurora0001 10q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong controller, so your controller's code (including the `$http.get`) never gets executed in the first place. Change `<div ng-controller="meetupsController">` to `<div ng-controller="mainpage">` so the `mainpage` controller's code gets executed.